# Collect git command's output with Go exec

Tags: go

I am extremely new to Go; as part of some innovation time, I decided to play around a bit with it. What I'd like to do is run some commands, and process their output.

I came up with this function to run commands:

```
func IssueCommand(command string, args []string) ([]string, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args[0:len(args)]...)

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    err = cmd.Start()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer cmd.Wait()
    buff := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

    var returnText []string

    for buff.Scan() {
        returnText = append(returnText, buff.Text())
    }

    return returnText, nil
}
```

I wanted to run this git command:

```
 git -C /something/something rev-list --count --date=local --all --no-merges
```

However, I keep getting an empty array as a result. I tried calling the function like this:

```
args := [7]string{"-C ", path, "rev-list", "--count", "--date=local", "--all", "--no-merges"}
result, err := IssueCommand("git", args[0:len(args)])
```

Also tried modifying the IssueCommand function to take a string for arguments; I called it like this:

```
cmd := "-C " + path + " rev-list --count --date=local --all --no-merges"
result, err := IssueCommand("git", cmd)
```

I got an empty array both times. It did capture output from commands like ls or pwd.

Again I am just trying to get a feel for Go, I will RTFM, but I have limited time for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intention is to run that command synchronously and get its output, the easiest way is to use [`cmd.Output()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Output) (run command and collect stdout) or [`cmd.CombinedOutput()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.CombinedOutput) (run command and collect stderr+stdout)

```
func IssueCommand(command string, args []string) ([]string, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)

    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    lines := strings.Split(string(out), "\n")
    return lines, nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks so much nicer indeed. However, it still returns empty results for my git commands. Not sure what's wrong with git.

Comment: Nevermind I was passing in the arguments incorrectly, it works well thank you!